# Put fully committed proposals waiting indefinitely in a separate place

Tags: feature-request, area-51, localization

I've noticed that we have quite a few fully committed proposals (Chinese Immigration, SO in Spanish, etc.) currently sitting at the top of the [A51 list sorted by progress](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress). I, for one, often use the list to see which sites are about to go into beta. It gives me a good grasp of what's happening around the network.

However, these fully-committed sites waiting on localization, be it site features or CM localization, dilute the signal coming from the progress list on A51. I'd like to propose that we make a new tab on A51 for "delayed sites", where these sites would live.

How's that sound?

Comment: Don't think it's worth the effort. It's only four sites and it's not likely to happen again. Plus, Area 51 is most likely going to give way to Area 52 at some point, with whole different design.

Comment: I heard they will all be launched in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Is Area52 on Area51? What state is it in? :-)

Comment: @Kerrek, Area 52 is in Kentucky.

Comment: @KerrekSB Area 52 will come instead of Area51, last I heard it was in advanced planning and it was [about a year ago](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/8922/46868). The employee leading the project (Robert) might have more info if you can contact him somehow.